# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "table": syntax error when trying to insert data

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to insert a 'strand' value from the csv file (sequences) into the table's 'sequence' column, but I am receiving an operational error for this line.

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO table (sequence) VALUES (?)", (sequences.row['strand']))
```

What's wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Start by changing the second argument to a tuple, ie `(sequences.row['strand'],)`. Then, are you sure such table exists? I don't believe you can call a table `table`

Comment: If your table is actually named table, it has to be quoted so sqlite knows it's a name and not a misplaced keyword. `insert into "table" values ...`. or use a better name.